# How to get value from enumeration given the name of the key

Tags: javascript, angular, enums

i have the below mentioned enumration. i know how to value of a color in the enumeration by specifying its index as follows:

```
Object.values(ColorEnum)[index]
```

what i want to know is how to get value stored in an enumeration given the key?in other words, how to get the values, for example,`#FF0B0B` by specifying the key `RED`

**code**:

```
export enum ColorEnum {
RED = "#FF0B0B",
RADICAL_RED = "2ff4357",
BRINK_POINK = "#fa6e8a",
PURPLE_PIZZAZZ = "#FF0BD1",

YELLOW = "#FFEB3B",
//RED2 = "#C62828",
GREEN = "#4CAF50",
//PINK2 = "#AD1457",
PURPLE = "#9C27B0",
//PURPLE2 = "#6A1B9A",
DEEP_PURPLE = "#4527A0",
INDIGO = "#536DFE",
BLUE = "#2196F3",
```

Comment: `ColorEnum.RED`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "RED" is in a string variable, you can get the enum's value using:

```
let color = "RED";
let colorCode = Color[color];
```